# In Rasterio - how to tile an array representing a geo-referenced image when the Affine object is separate?

Tags: python, arrays, gis, rasterio

I am attempting to tile a large image (.img format, but could be geotiff), however I have already cropped the image using [rasterio mask](https://mapbox.github.io/rasterio/api/rasterio.mask.html.) which returns a masked array and a separate Affine object.

```
from rasterio import mask
import fiona

image = rasterio.open(image_path)
with fiona.open(shapefile_path, 'r') as shapefile:
    cropping_polygon = [polygon['geometry'] for polygon in shapefile]

smaller_image, smaller_image_affine = mask.mask(image, cropping_polygon, crop=True)
```

Now I want to split the `smaller_image` into tiles of a fixed size. I have looked at rasterio windowed reading and writing but this seems to rely on the image having the `image.affine` attribute in order not to lose the geo-referencing.

Is it possible to tile the masked array, and produce a new affine for each tile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `rasterio.windows.transform`.

```
tile_window = rasterio.windows.Window(0, 0, 256, 256)
tile_affine = rasterio.windows.transform(tile_window, smaller_image_affine)
tile_image = smaller_image[(slice(None),) + tile_window.toslices()]
```

Then with `tile_image` and `tile_affine` you have all the pieces you need to write this to a new file.

Comment: Perfect answer thank you - not sure how I missed this!